# Magento custom attribute value to be shown on cart page

Tags: php, magento

In Magento,I have functionality where, a product has multiple colors, user can select quantity and color for product on product view page, where a product has different colors,

I need to show selected color on  a cart page.
I tried following code.

```
  <?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo     $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

but it returns all color values for a product on cart page, instead of selected value for cart page.

any ideas?

Comment: You have to convert each such product to configurable product (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-configurable-product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main options for a product to have multiple colors:

1. Configurable products:
   If you are using configurable products then you can get you color attribute like this:

   ```
   <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('color_attribute')); echo $product->getColorAttribute(); ?></code>
   ```

   Replace 'color_attribute' and getColorAttribute with your attribute name.
2. Custom options:
   In this case use:

   ```
   <?php print_r($_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct())); ?>
   ```

   And look for the options you need to display.

Comment: Hi you can follow this link  http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2013/11/get-product-attribute-on-cart-page.html.It works perfect for me

Comment: Basically it's the same thing I posted at nr. 1